# executeAsync strange behavior - sharepoint rest services

Tags: web-part, 2013, jquery, rest, updatelistitems

I'm using Sharepoint Rest services to update List Items. To do the update, I'm using the function `executeAsync` from the `SP.RequestExecutor` object. The code was working fine, but while I was testing it today, I realized the `ListItems` weren't updating and the `executeAsync` function was working fine ( going to the success function and there were no errors).

```
function ActualizarDatosListaConItemType(urlSitio, nomlista, id, metadata, funcionExito, funcionError, itemType, esAsync) {
// Prepping our update
var item = $.extend({ "__metadata": { "type": itemType } }, metadata);
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(urlSitio);
executor.executeAsync({
url: urlSitio + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + nomlista + "')/items('" + id + "')",
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
data: JSON.stringify(item),
headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
          "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
          "If-Match": "*"
          },
 success: function (data) { funcionExito(data); },
 error: function (data) { funcionError(data); }
 });
}
```